# NullPointerException when comparing String parameters in Java

Tags: java, servlets, nullpointerexception

I'm using a servlet as controller for redirect pages. So, I have the following links:

```
<li><a href="actionController?key=contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="actionController?key=support">Request support</a></li>
```

I want receives in this parameters in my controller and redirect the request from pages for the page Contact.jsp, for example.

Therefore, I assume that would be:

```
    contact = request.getParameter("contact");

    support = request.getParameter("support");

    if (contact.equals("contato"))
    {
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/center/Contact.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);        
    }
    else if (support.equals("support"))
    {
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/center/Support.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
```

However, is not working, is with java.lang.NullPointerException.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Your servlet-code doesn't seem to match your HTML-snippet. I think you need to write:

```
    String key = request.getParameter("key");

    if (key != null && key.equals("contact"))
    {
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/center/Contact.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);        
    }
    else if (key != null && key.equals("support"))
    {
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/center/Support.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: You can also check it the other way round like so `if ("contact".equals(key))`. The string literal `"contact"` is namely already guaranteed to be not `null` :)

Comment: @BalusC: Absolutely -- that's actually how I *usually* do this in my own code -- but the OP seemed to be confused about null-pointer-exceptions in general, so I thought this way might make it more clear what's going wrong. :-)

Answer (score 1):

First get the `key` value using param name as `key` (**this is the root cause of your problem**) then simply put the string literals as first argument in comparison to avoid any `NullPointerExceotion` as:

```
String key = request.getParameter("key");
if ("contact".equals(key)){
    RequestDispatcher view = 
                       request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/center/Contact.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);        
}else if ("support".equals(key)){
    RequestDispatcher view = 
                       request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/center/Support.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);
}
```

If required, add the default handling as well i.e. handling the scenario where `key` is neither `contact` nor `support`.

Answer (score 0):

This means, no "contact" or "support" parameters, are found. Check if they are null before you use them.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
    String key = request.getParameter("key");

    if(null == key){
    // do something

    } else if(key.equals("contact")){
    // do something else

    } else if(key.equals("support")){
    // do something else

    } else {
    // etc

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request will not contain any "contact" or "support" parameters, but instead will contain a "key" parameter.

I recommend you take a look at [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) - explains URI syntax, including query parameters.